# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

```
for i in range(0,len(final3)):
    default=final3["DefaultValue"].iloc[i]
    if (not(default.contains("|"))):
        if(final3["DefaultValue"].iloc[i] in final3["CodedData"].iloc[i]):
            final3["Condition"].iloc[i]="False"
        else:
            final3["Condition"].iloc[i]="True"
```

"DefaultValue" column contains values like "1|2|3". So, I tried to split the string using delimiter and check if it exist in the "CodedData" column in the same row. "CodedData" contains values like "3|4" But I am facing the attribute error.

Comment: `str` has no method `contains` where did you see that documented? You could say `if not '|' in default`

Comment: it gives you python's string which doesn't have `default.contains()` and you should use `if "|" not in default`

Comment: @CoryKramer `str.contains` is a method for pandas Series btw, the OP misused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that you're trying to use `.contains()` on a string which is not a string function.

Try:

```
for i in range(0,len(final3)):
    default = final3["DefaultValue"].iloc[i]
    if not "|" in default:
        if default in final3["CodedData"].iloc[i]:
            final3["Condition"].iloc[i] = "False"
        else:
            final3["Condition"].iloc[i] = "True"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way i can split default using delimiter "|" and store it in a string array

Comment: You should ask that as a new question and mark this one answered.

Answer (score 1):

In python strings, there is no method contains. Instead python has a simple syntax for that. You can use the following in place of `default.contains("|")`

```
"|" in default
#or
"|" not in default
```